# Error by installing a Package

Tags: errors, packages, miktex, installing

I am using the MikTex Package Manager in order to install the emptypage package.
I get the following error and I do not know what to do.

MiKTeX Problem Report

Message: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.

Data:

Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\RestRemoteService.cpp

Line: 233

MiKTeX: 2.9

OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 18363

Invokers: non-existing/explorer

SystemAdmin: no

PowerUser: no

Root0: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9

Root1: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9

Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9

UserInstall: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9

UserConfig: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9

UserData: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9

CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9

CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

Comment: I'm sorry but if it is up to impossible to debug this type of error. I can install packages so miktex is not generally offline or broken, it must be something on your machine. If you can't repair it you could try texlive instead.

Comment: Not a solution for your real problem, but maybe you already have installed KOMA-Script. In this case you can use package `scrextend` instead of `emptypage` as a workaround. It does also switch to page style `empty` for empty pages with `\cleardoublepage`.